# Summation notation with multiple subscripts

Tags: notation

I am not sure how exactly to interpret this kind of notation.

I understand the second one to read sum of over $k$ of $\gamma_{k,j}$ is equal to zero. Is that the same as:

$\gamma_{1,1}+\gamma_{2,1}+\gamma_{3,1}\dots=0$

$\gamma_{1,2}+\gamma_{2,2}+\gamma_{3,2}\dots=0$

etc...

Thank you so much.
[image]

Comment: the attachment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lanc8t8gnuxu9ov/sum.png

Answer (score 1):

It might have been clearer if they wrote $$\sum_j \gamma_{kj}=0 \quad \sum_k \gamma_{kj}=0$$  Your understanding is correct.  You can think of the $\gamma_{jk}$ as filling up an array.  The first one says the sum of any column is zero, the second that the sum of any row is zero.